# Query image from SalesForce as blob

Tags: community, forcetk

Is there any way I can query the image from SalesForce server as a blob object ? We already have forcetk client queries which is retrieving all the data, but the image alone is returned as a link (salesforce link).

Can we retrieve image as blob in the same REST query call ?

The methods I saw required to make an extra call to fetch images, but here I have images in each row of the result, it would have been better if images come as a part of result object itself.

Comment: Insufficient information. Which objects are you querying from? What do your queries look like? We probably have an answer for you, but the devil is in the details.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did any one resolved this issue?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did any one resolved this issue?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the REST API, then the blob data can't be returned with the rest of the object, it has to be a separate request. If you use SOAP then it can inline the blob data with the rest of the fields for the object, but it will be limited to returning one row at a time.

Comment: I am trying the rest api but not able to fetch this blob with plain image call

Comment: update your question, i have no idea what you mean by a plain image call.